# Migrating ETH 2.0 staking stack from one machine to another on the go

Tags: proof-of-stake, eth-2.0, staking

I was reading through the eth docs but could not see any info about following:

> What can be the possible problems of migrating my ETH2.0 staking stack infrastructure from one machine to another.

I was thinking to start on machine X (my own hw or VPS) and then switch to machine Y that can be somewhere else physically and again be:

- or dedicated cloud server
- or my own machine

In order to do that, I would simply try to migrate the blockchain data, nodes & wallets 1:1 from one machine to another then stop one and let the other catch up (possibly eat some penalties for some short downtime).

Are there some other things that can go wrong - for example:

- would not moving the staking machine from Europe to US cause problems?
- something I miss completely?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok so to answer my own question in case of someone asking the same in the future: There is something called `slashing protection history` which needs to be migrated from machine to machine as well, otherwise it should be straightforward. Gonna test on testnet anyway.

If you are using Prysm:

- https://medium.com/interdax/ethereum-2-0-explainer-e996ac7dc006
- https://docs.prylabs.network/docs/wallet/slashing-protection/